# Microsoft SQL 2016 database for Malwarebytes Endpoint Protection

Tags: sql-server-2016, errors

I don't know if this is the correct forum, but hopefully someone can help.

I am a newly promoted entry level Systems Administrator and the first project I was tasked with was to spin up a new server and install Malwarebytes Endpoint Protection utilizing an external database. I got everything spunned up, however, Malwarebytes won't connect to the database. When it prompts for me to choose "Use Embedded Database," or "Use External Database" I choose the "use external." I then type in the database address, which is the server and instance, then the username and password. This is where I get hung up. I get an error message stating "Login failed for user ..." "Installation was unable to access the database."

Now in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, under Security --> Logins I've created a user and I've set its Server Roles to dbcreator and sysadmin. However, I've tried the credential I've just created and other credentials that are on our AD domain admin users, and no matter which credential I've tried, it still won't let me login to install. Am I missing a step?

Comment: This has been resolved. Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

If the application required a user name and a password, that means it attempts to connect using SQL Authentication and not using Windows AD authentication.

By default, SQL Server allows only for Windows Authentication, so you you need to enable the "mixed authentication" mode for SQL server. It can be enabled when installing, but if you used the defaults, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode) on how to change the server authentication mode.

Also make sure that the user you are creating on the SQL Server is a SQL login and not a windows login. It should be:

```
CREATE LOGIN <login_name> WITH PASSWORD = 'Password'
```

and not

```
CREATE LOGIN [<domainName>\<login_name>] FROM WINDOWS
```

HTH